# Generate data from posterior predictive distribution

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, monte-carlo

I am new to Bayesian. I want to draw data from the posterior predictive distribution p(y|D).

Do we need to find the CDF of the posterior predictive distribution and use the monte Carlo method or is there another way for simulation in bayesian?

my model has a complicated posterior predictive distribution p(y|D), so I cannot derive CDF. if I can use monte Carlo, can I draw data with pdf?

Comment: Could you tell us something about the posterior?

Comment: Generally, people will use Markov-chain Monte Carlo to generate samples from posteriors/posterior predictives.

Comment: Let's say we have Weibull distribution with unknown scale and shape parameters where the scale parameter has Gamma and the shape has N(mu, sigma)

Comment: I got this R code here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499933/application-of-metropolis-hastings which helps me understand M-H MCMC to estimate parameters but I do not understand how to generate data from the posterior predictive distribution

Answer (score 1):

If $p(x | \theta)$ denotes the distribution of the data ($\theta$ denoting the parameter) and $\pi(\theta | x^{\textrm{obs}})$ denotes the posterior distribution of $\theta$ then you can simulate from the posterior predictive distribution by applying this two-stages procedure:

- simulate $\theta$ according to $\pi(\theta | x^{\textrm{obs}})$;
- then simulate an observation $x$ according to $p(x | \theta)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in the second stage How can I simulate data? Do I need to use transformation (inverse sampling)?

Comment: @Mmmm What is the distribution of your data and which software do you use?

Comment: I use the Weibull distribution of my data with unknown scale and shape parameters and I use the R programme. similar to this question answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499933/application-of-metropolis-hastings but I have the prior for the scale parameter is Gamma and normal distribution for the shape parameter.

Comment: @Mmmm So you can use the `rweibull` function.

Comment: yes, you are right for the likelihood data but what I mean here is sampling from the predictive posterior distribution

Comment: @Mmmm I mean use `rweibull` for the second step of the procedure.

Comment: why do we use Weibull for the second step? might I not understand. As I know the posterior predictive distribution is a product of pdf and posterior with integrated for theta.